# What does Shilov mean by a "vector of absolute divergence"?

Tags: real-analysis

In *Real and Complex Analysis*, Problem 6-18, Shilov defines a *vector of absolute divergence*: https://books.google.com/books?id=GELCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA222&dq=shilov+solid+angle&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RTrIVLrOH8S8UarLgfgH&ved=0CCUQ6wEwAQ#v=onepage&q=shilov%20solid%20angle&f=false

I really don't know what he's talking about.  Do you understand?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this lovely book.

Answer (score 0):

It means there are a lot of terms of the series with direction close to that vector, not only in number, but also in sum of absolute values. The part of the series in any cone containing $q$ is absolutely divergent. To be precise:

for every $\epsilon >0$ the sum

$$\sum_{ \text{angle} (u_n, q) < \epsilon} ||u_n|| = \infty$$

Just think : if you have a series $\sum u_n$ with $u_n \in \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, what does it mean that $(-1,0)$ is a vector of absolute divergence?